# Drawing an X with C with ONLY While-loops & If-Statements

Tags: c, while-loop, printf

An assignment we have been given is to draw an X in C using only while loops and if statements (maths and expressions are allowed).

I have only done the first half of the X in code, as the other half is just the reverse.

The challenging part is the middle dashes (-), as I'm struggling to find a way to make them count backward by 2 through while loops.

Am I overthinking this way too much? If so, what would be a better approach to this problem?

This is my first time learning C and we are not allowed for loops or anything beyond a basic level.

Thanks for reading!

```
    int size, fLine, rowCounter, tempSize;

    printf("Enter size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    // The split will half the size of the X to run 2 seperate while loops
    // One loop for the top half and another for the lower half.
    int split = ((size - 1) / 2);
    int row = 1;

    // Top half of the X
    while (row <= split) {
        // Condition to print out the top and bottom line of the X
        if ((row == 1) || (row == size)) {
            printf("*");
            // tempSize will allow for the counter to decrease without 
            // affecting the size variable
            tempSize = size;

            // Will add the middle dashes on the top line
            while ((tempSize - 2) > 0) {
                printf("-");
                tempSize--;
            }
            printf("*\n");
            row++;
        } else {
            // The dashes before the first asterisks
            // rowCounter allows the row number to be decreased in the 
            // while loop
            rowCounter = row - 1;
            while (rowCounter > 0) {
                printf("-");
                rowCounter--;
            }
            printf("*");

            // Will add size + (row * -2) dashes into the middle
            // **This section is the subject of the question!**
            rowCounter = row * 2;
            tempSize = rowCounter - size; // 2 - 5 = -3
            while (tempSize < (size - 1)) {
                printf("-");
                tempSize++;
            }
            printf("*");
            // Will add the final dashes. Exactly the same as the first 
            // while loop
            rowCounter = row - 1;
            while (rowCounter > 1) {
                printf("-");
                rowCounter--;
            }
            printf("-\n");
            row++;
        } //Yet to add the middle line and the bottom half!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Result:

```
Enter Size: 5  
*---*  
-*-*-
--*--
-*-*-
*---*
```

Actual Result:

```
Enter Size: 5
*---*
-*-----*-
```

I want the middle values to count BACKWARD so 9, 7, 5, 3, 1, etc., instead of upwards by 2.

Comment: What formatting issue do you mean? `*`s are properly displayed as `*`s when formated properly as code.

Comment: @glglgl Oops sorry, I've fixed the code now. Thanks for the spot

Comment: Your code is incomplete, it cannot be compiled and run. Variables `size`, `tempSize` and `rowCounter` are not declared. It would be easier to understand your code if you would explain the purpose of the variables. I suggest to add comments to the code or change the variable names to make the purpose clear. For example if you "want the middle values to count BACKWARD" you should write which variable is used for the "middle values". Please [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: @Bodo I'm sorry for the misunderstanding but I excluded them from the code example as to not copy and paste the entire file. They are declared. But your suggestions for comments are a great idea to help clear it up. Sorry its a little unclear because I'm struggling to understand it myself.

Comment: If possible you should show code that can be used to show your problem by compiling (and running) it, so it should be complete in this regard. Of course you should simplify the code as much as possible to contain only the parts needed to show the problem.

Comment: @Bodo Oh alright sorry I'm new here and didn't know. I will definitely take that on board for the future. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a much easier solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
int size, i=0, j=0;
printf("Please Enter a Odd Size: \n")
scanf(%d, &size);
while(size%2==0)
{
    printf("Only Odd size is ok \n");
    printf("Please Enter a Odd Size: \n")
    scanf(%d, &size);
}

while(i<size)
{
    j=0;
    while(j<size)
    {
        if(j == i || i == (size-1)-j)
        {
            printf("!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("-");
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    i++;
}
```

the output is:

!---!

-!-!-

--!--

-!-!-

!---!

Comment: Oh okay that is a lot more simple approach to this issue. Thank you very much for your help!!! :))

Comment: It would be helpful to add some explanation and use variable names that show the purpose, e.g `row` and `column` instead of `i` and `j`. I think `j == size - 1 - i` (or better `column == size - 1 - row`) is clearer than `i == (size-1)-j`

Comment: @Bodo Great idea to help with the readability! Thanks heaps guys!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I messed around a little:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {

    int size = 5;

   if( size % 2 == 1 )
   {
      fprintf( stdout, "now drawing\n");

      int lineCount = 0;

      int lastPost = size - 1;

      while( lineCount < size )
      {
          int rowCount = 0;

          while( rowCount < size )
          {
              if( ( rowCount == lineCount ) 
                  || ( rowCount == lastPost ) )
              {
                  fprintf( stdout, "X");
              }
              else
              {
                  fprintf( stdout, ".");
              }

              ++rowCount;
          }

          fprintf( stdout, "\n");

          --lastPost;            
          ++lineCount;
      }
  }
  else
  {
      fprintf( stderr, "size must be odd!\n");
  }

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Whilst I understand how your code runs and appreciate the answer, I personally have never seen fprintf, stderr, & stdout before. I will go and investigate those now!  And I do like the interesting error message and "now drawing" output. Thanks! :)